# Error:no such file when using fs.outputJsonSync

Tags: node.js, solidity

I have a problem like this. I have created a compile.js file to compile my solidity Contract. In there to handle file I am using the fs-extra module.

This is my compile.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath= path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath,'utf8');
const output= solc.compile(source,1).contracts;

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for(let contract in output){
    fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath,contract),
        output[contract]
    );
}
```

It works everything finely, without for each loop. When I compile this file with for loop it gives me an error saying that

```
C:\Users\tharindusa\WebstormProjects\Campaign\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Modu
le)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};fo
r(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[k
ey]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=ty
peof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"
&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var EN
VIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WOR
KER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x)
{process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=funct
ion printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nod
ePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=node
Path["normalize"](filename);var ret=nodeFS["readFileSy

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tharindusa\WebstormProje
cts\Campaign\ethereum\build\:Campaign.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1299:33)
    at Object.writeFileSync (C:\Users\tharindusa\WebstormProjects\Campaign\node_m
odules\fs-extra\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:117:13)
    at Object.outputJsonSync (C:\Users\tharindusa\WebstormProjects\Campaign\node_
modules\fs-extra\lib\json\output-json-sync.js:15:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tharindusa\WebstormProjects\Campaign\ethereum\compile.js:15:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? .Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filename (`:Campaign.json`) contains a colon, which is invalid in Windows, where colons are only used with drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same problem while compiling my contracts.The issue with your code is that it tries to create a file named :Campaign which is not allowed in windows.

I used the following code to get around it

```
for(let contract in output){
    fs.outputJSONSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath,contract.replace(/:/g,'')+'.json'),
        output[contract]
    );
}
```